# sql query count multiple rows between two dates

Tags: sql-server

Greetings,
I am trying to build a query that will provide me with the totals of all records (some records are recurring) between two dates. I am stuck at the following query:

```
SELECT DISTINCT Country, COUNT(Country) as Count, Date 
From DataSet 
GROUP BY Country, Date 
ORDER BY Country HAVING Date>'1/1/2000'
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

```
  SELECT DISTINCT Country, COUNT (Country) AS COUNT
    FROM DataSet
   WHERE Date BETWEEN '01-01-2010' AND '01-01-2011'
GROUP BY Country
ORDER BY Country
```

You should not group by date because you'll get for every date a row

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT Country, COUNT(DISTINCT Country) as "Count"
FROM DataSet  GROUP BY Country, Date
HAVING Date>'1/1/2000';
```

because `HAVING`  are not set with order by ok coorect it

Comment: you only need to use the HAVING clause if you are filtering on the aggregate (SUM, COUNT).  So if you want all the records where the Count is greater than 10 you would use HAVING COUNT(*) > 10.  If you are just filtering on a value, it should be in the WHERE clause.